# My PHP page (or form) decode automatically html entities

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with my form that send variables to a page that have TCPDF to print values:

if I write this directly inside my textarea:

```
<p>&lt;TEST</p>
```

and click submit, my destination page, using var_dump show me:

```
<p><TEST</p>
```

That result BREAK my TCPDF building!

Why result are automatically decoded? How to prevent this?

My destination page:

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['testo'];

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 8, '', true);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->writeHTML($text, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Comment: show us the code that's being used in pdf generation...

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo hi I've included a piece of code. The problem is that if I include var_dump($text) also before start of TCPDF code, I see already decoded variable!

Comment: I suspect <p>TEST</p> is what YOU see in your browser. Please have a look at the raw source code of your html page, e.g. press CTRL+u in Chrome to view the real source code delivered. Waht you see might not be what you get ;-)

Comment: @maxhb I've done some test: I use summernote editor to write text. If I write "I <3 TEXT" in the editor, if I switch to souce-code viewer I see: "<p>I &lt;3 TEXT</p>" that is ok. But submitting it, I get: "<p>I <3 TEXT</p>", the &lt; is automatically decoded. Using CTRL-I in my firefox souce, I see: <p>I <3 TEXT</p>